# Angularjs - create globally accessible (accessible in templates too) function in a module

Tags: javascript, angularjs

We want to create a reusable library/module for our ACL functionality. Basically, to check if the logged-in user has access to the particular UI resource and also has permissions to perform actions like click etc... So, we want to expose a hasAccess() function which can be called from inside directives like - ng-show, ng-hide, ng-disabled etc...

We explored few options like angular-acl (https://github.com/mikemclin/angular-acl). With this solution, in every controller, we need to add a line like this: $scope.can = AclService.can; which is bit pain, given that we are having many controllers in our application.

So, was exploring on what is the best way this can be achieved? Is there a way we can export global functions from inside our module service, so that the same is accessible in every template?

Some of the solutions we found was to write code inside module.run() method, and set $rootScope.fn = . But, can we write a run() for a module that is being shared as a library? Is this valid, and if yes, then, when exactly will this run() be called is not clear.

Any idea, what is the best practice solution for such a scenario, where we want to expose a global method/function from inside a service, such that the same can be accessed in templates?

Comment: its javascript... anything is doable. you could even prototype the methods you need into angular. Remember, you are not forced to angulars method base. I would suggest modifying angulars functions by wrapping them into another function that has the check if a user has  permission.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Michael. Ny ways, looks like we can write run method for a module. So, I'm able to set the global function in rootScope!